# Adapting a percentage value based on input

Tags: average, percentages, data-analysis

I have a program that I need to maintain a certain percentage, between 10-15 percent of subcounts to majorcounts.

```
Test data:

 Time       subcount    majorcount
 10:20             1            30
 10:30             3            40
 10:40             5            50
 10:50            10           100
 11:20            20           400
 11:40            10           200
#11:50           200           200

        sum(248)      sum(1020)

        perc(248/1020) = 24.31
```

The last addition is what I am to add to my data if it is within the 10-15% range and it does not take my dataset overall over or under my range.

If it does take my dataset over, How can I identify the amount of subcounts to remove or the majorcounts to add to maintain the 10-15% requirement?

In the case above, I have a 24% that I would need to attempt to drop down to 15 using only the last values added identified by the #.

Comment: Not following.  Are you saying you get to add a new entry to your database such that the new calculation gives a value in the preferred range?  And what does it mean to "take my dataset over"?

Comment: I can manipulate the sub count of the last item by removing some or manipulate the major count by adding

Comment: Ok, so you get to overwrite the last entry in any way you choose in order to get the desired value?  This is a very odd database.

Comment: The intent is to maintain a 10-15% average in a rolling 4 hour period

Comment: So your real mathematical question is: What number $a$ should I add to $x$ so that $x+a= 0.15 y$ ? Well, it sounds like you only need to calculate what the right-hand side is, and then subtract $x$ from it ....

Comment: By fabricating data?  I don't see the point.  But, if that's what you want, then just keep column $A$ constant and modify the last entry in column $B$ as desired.  Here the $A-$sum is $248$ so if you want the percent to be, say, $10\%$ then you need the $B-$ sum to be $2480$. So...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use markup and margin.  $24.31\%$ is  $62 {2\over 3}\%$ markup on $15\%$ which means you need to take away at least $$38.52459016\%$$ of the sum of subcounts. to land within the range, and by similar logic you can calculate for no less than $10\%$. or you can just markup the majorcount within the relevant markups calculated. One last option is to mix the two strategies, but honestly, it seems a wasted effort.